# C++: Best way to access overloaded operator++ with std::unique_ptr?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, unique-ptr

If I have a class with an overloaded operator++, for example:

In header:

```
SomeClass& operator++(int);
```

Implementation:

```
SomeClass& SomeClass::operator++(int) { someLocalVar++; return this; }
```

If I then instantiate `SomeClass` in an `std::unique_ptr`:

```
std::unique_ptr<SomeClass> someClass(new SomeClass());
```

And I then want to call `operator++` some `someClass`, I use:

```
someClass.get()->operator++(0);
```

I understand I could do something like:

```
SomeClass *ptrSomeClass = someClass.release();
ptrSomeClass++;
```

but this is also quite lengthy, and kind of defeats the purposes of using `std::unique_ptr` in the first place.

If there a better way of calling an overloaded `operator++` with `std::unique_ptr`?

Comment: `(*ptr)++` or `++(*ptr)`?

Comment: You should absolutely not call `.release()`, which releases the ownership of the object by the `std::unique_ptr`. If at all you would call `.get()`, which does not release ownership. In either case you get back a pointer, so `ptrSomeClass++;` doesn't do what you want it to do either.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt The former. `operator++(int)` is postfix (and is then called with argument `0`). `operator++()` is prefix.

Comment: `SomeClass& operator++(int);` is poor style; postfix-++ should return by value (because it returns the old state whilst updating the object to the new state).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The exact same way you do with any other pointer to your object type - dereference the pointer first, then apply your desired operation to the underlying object that is being pointed at.  `std::unique_ptr` has overloaded `->` and `*` dereference operators to provide similar semantics as raw pointers, eg:

```cpp
std::unique_ptr<SomeClass> someClass(new SomeClass);
...
someClass->operator++(0);
```

Or:

```cpp
std::unique_ptr<SomeClass> someClass(new SomeClass);
...
(*someClass)++;
```